# Is there any way to leave proposed edits alone while also editing?

Tags: support, editing-help

A question has a proposed edit that tries to fix the indentation of OP's Python code. The problem is that, while OP has failed in formatting the code properly for posting, *it is not clear how OP has actually indented the original code*; the suggested edit *may or may not* be correct.

In the meantime, I wish to fix, say, the spelling or grammar of surrounding text, or remove noise.

Is there any way I can make my changes without discarding the proposed edit, so that the other editor can possibly get credit later if the edit is correct?

Comment: If you don't know Python you may just leave the question alone... If you do know Python than it sounds like you should "reject and edit" the change as you don't believe the edit is valid... (also for gold tag user of Python it is somewhat strange that you can't decide if pending edit is correct or not - who else you expect to know the answer - diamond python users?)

Comment: I know Python. I *don't know* if the edit is valid because *the point of the question* is that *depending on what OP actually wrote*, the answer is different, but we don't know for sure what OP wrote. The other editor's interpretation *may be correct*, or it may not be.

Comment: I noticed your gold badge there after posting initial version of comment :)  I don't see who can make that "valid/invalid" decision if you as gold tag user can't ...

Comment: OP can - hopefully. The idea is that OP messed up when posting the code, and the real code could look two different ways.

Comment: If you want to give OP chance to apply the change "reject" with custom message would probably be the best way as they will see the change and may be able to apply it with they binding vote, but that likely invalid change is not forced on OP. I don't know  if "Reject and Edit" would create visible entry for OP to look at... I would not worry about editor is not getting reward because if edit requires meta post to decide if it is valid it probably should not be done to start with.

Comment: IMO, you do know the edit is *not valid*. What we need to see is the indenting that the OP *actually used*. If there's a proposed edit from someone else, it has a significant chance of influencing the OP. It's not unlikely that the OP will just accept the edit, without regard to if it matches the indenting which the OP was actually using. There have been a *lot* of times when I've see OPs accept edits which are quite poor, even ones which inappropriately mess with their code.The edit you describe is definitely one I'd reject with a custom reason, then force an edit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To my knowledge there is no way to make such edits.

I also don't think it will ever be implemented. Merging changes in multi-way merge is hard and often require manual intervention, so I don't see it being done over simple merge (more like clobber) SO using now.

About this particular case I think "Reject" (or "Reject and Edit") is appropriate action as there is really no one more qualified to make call on whether edit changes actual problem in the question as gold-badge user in the language tag.

Comment: Thanks for talking through this. I think you are right.

Comment: @Alexei, in Python, indentation affects how the compiler reads the code. That's why only the OP can really say which indentation is correct. So being a gold-badge user doesn't really make any difference, if the intention from the OP is unclear.

Comment: @marcellothearcane I don't get your point, sorry - can you please clarify? An edit in the edits review queue must be reviewed  by 3-5 random (only requirement is more than 2k rep) people and decision must be made if it is valid (improves the post and definitely  keeps original meaning) or not (doesn't improve the post or potentially changes the meaning). I don't understand why you think why random user that may not even know syntax of the language is equally qualified to make valid/invalid decision on the edit as gold-badge user in the language tag.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov As an analogy, consider `3 x 4 x 5 ÷ 6 + 7 – 8`. Depending on where the brackets are, the answer can be several things. Equally, with Python, depending on where indentation is in the code, the issue might be different. That's why the OP would need to say where the indentation is (or the brackets are) to explain exactly what the issue _they_ are facing is.

Comment: @marcellothearcane can you please explain how OP is related to review queue? (I get that Python uses significant whitespace, but I don't see how it is significant to the question - there are a lot of edits that look like style edits in any language that can invalidate question, properly formatting Python code is just one of such changes)