# Should I just wait until I get 2k rep to make 1-character spelling mistake edits?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

I've been editing many posts recently but am having a large percentage of edit suggestions that are only minor spelling mistakes rejected, and then manually edited by the rejecter.

I understand how it comes across editing minor mistakes, either lazy or repfarming.

However, I think it reflects even poorly on the character of the rejecter who makes zero changes to the rejected edit and does the exact same edit of the typo.

It is not the responsibility of the edit reviewer to examine the motives of whomever submits reviews, but the content of and the improvements bequeathed by the edit itself.

And I feel as if I am potentially going to get edit banned, simply because some edit "reviewers" don't think I deserve +2 reputation for making minor spelling mistake edits.

Comment: Even when your edits are not reviewed you shouldn’t be submitting a single character edits. As somebody who reviewed tons of edit proposals, if an edit is incomplete, I routinely decline their edit proposal. If a user is not willing to correct all obvious errors in a contribution, I am typically unwilling, to fix them myself.

Comment: @SecurityHound "Even when your edits are not reviewed you shouldn’t be submitting a single character edits." I do and I think one should. Every edit improves the site (on average), so doing edits is better than not doing the edits in the case where you do not impose review burdens.

Comment: @Trilarion - Best to solve all problems with a question in a single edit. Saving everyone unnecessary work. The general guidelines of editing support my Philosophy

Comment: @SecurityHound *"Edits cause questions to appear in review queues"* No it doesn't, not anymore, there's [a checkbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/szhLw.png) for pushing posts into queues when editing.

Comment: "I think it reflects even poorly on the character of the rejecter" Or perhaps, just perhaps, they don't want the system clogged down with superfluous edits taking up several people's reviews?

Comment: Why go around correcting tiny "mistakes".  If the poster is a non-native speaker would you "fix" idioms, or would you correct english vs. american spelling differences?  Don't take ownership of the question from someone when your edit makes **no** difference.  There are tons of bad questions, and correcting these little deviations is not useful: let the asker speak with their own voice, perfect or not.

Comment: Also, why are you editing "many" posts.  I've always wondered what all these nonsense edits are that I review.  Do you get rep for doing this?

Comment: @Andrew This is a community-curated site, so yes, [editing content to improve it is a first class operation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) and is indeed encouraged. _"Do you get rep for doing this?"_ No, unless you have less than 2000 reputation, in which edit approvals grant a few points.

Comment: You shouldn't bother the edit reviewers with such minor edits. But please note that fixing grammar/spelling _is_ a valid edit and should not get rejected either. That is, unless you failed to fix other obvious problems with the post at the same time - edits should be as substantial as possible. Check grammar, spelling, title, formatting, tags - everything.

Comment: @OlegValter There's still a limit on 1k rep from suggested edits, so not, that's not possible :p

Comment: @Nick is it valid for tag wiki/excerpt suggested edits too? Phew then, nice to hear that this is not possible

Comment: @Andrew "...correcting these little deviations is not useful..." That's not true. Everything is useful if it improves the content, little or big. It's just about not wasting the time of others.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

## [Yes.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/77257/175248)

Every edit you do makes its way into the edit queue.  It's better to make large amounts of changes if the question or answer needs it than *just* fixing a typo or two.

Answer (score 29):

As one of the rejectors you're talking about, I will say: yes, when making edits (as a suggestor, it's less of a concern when making edits directly as a >2k user) you should be doing what you can to ***fix every issue you can identify in the posts you are editing***.

Immediately identifiable issues missed in some of your reviews are:

| Edit | Reasons to reject |
| --- | --- |
| https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/30392918 | Did not remove *"Appreciate any help."*; did not remove unnecessary indentation in code; and did not add code formatting where appropriate. |
| https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/30382740 | Did not correct poor capitalization (`i`, etc.); did not remove unnecessary spaces before colons; did not address *"any exchange is acceptable!!"* |
| https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/30382735 | Did not remove *"Thank you."*; did not format table appropriately. |

It's not that your edits were *bad*, simply that they weren't extensive enough: you could've (and should've) done more.

---

While it is possible for you to have your edit privileges suspended (either automatically for having too many of your edit suggestions rejected or manually suspended by a moderator), I can say that I didn't flag for moderator action because *not all your edits are that bad*.

Your historical edits (or at least *some* of them) *were* more extensive.

The rejections are intended more as a wake-up call to say: Hey, it's clear you know what you're doing, so why did you stop being so extensive?

Answer (score 14):

### Yes, thou should

Seconding Makoto's [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/413274/11407695), each and every edit suggestion makes it into the review queue, where it takes place of another possible, more complete edit - the queue is limited to 500 submissions at a time.

This also creates friction to established users trying to curate tag wikis and excerpts as their detailed submissions have to wait in the same queue while reviewers are busy checking "filee" to "file" edits (did I mention that reviewers have a quota on the number of daily reviews? And limited time and patience?).

---

Regarding some of the points made in your question:

> It is not the responsibility of the edit reviewer to examine the motives

True. The responsibility of a reviewer is to ensure the quality  *and completeness* of suggested edits meet the editing guidelines. With that said, let us go through another couple of such edits, shall we (since Nick already addressed some of them)?

| Edit | Reasons to reject |
| --- | --- |
| https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/30398470 | error message is not formatted properly, non-runnable snippet not removed (this is Node.js, fcs!), code not formatted |
| https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/30398472 | Noise not removed, capitalization not fixed |
| https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/30419022 | adds a tag to title (explicitly against the guidelines), makes unnecessary stylistic changes, changes 4 spaces to code block - a user preference |

> simply because some edit "reviewers" don't think I deserve +2 reputation

No, no one feels you personally do not deserve the reputation. What reviewers rejecting minor typos feel is that such edits violate one of the most important [editing guidelines](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/303220/11407695) have:

> Make your edits as complete as possible

I would also tone down on the passive-agressive style towards reviewers. Those are people who volunteer their time to ensure quality of submitted edits - respect their effort.

> I am potentially going to get edit banned

No, you are not. The formula for determining the automatic ban is [as follows](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92337/786798):

```
(rejects - (approvals / 3)) >= 5
```

At the time of this writing, you have 40 approved and 9 rejected edits, which means that the coefficient is `-4.3` — a very long way to the ban unless you start to submit utter trash for a while. Far from all your suggestions are bad, just take into account the feedback from fellow volunteers, and you will be all good.

Comment: Damn, I wish I'd chosen a table to format my reasoning, much neater

Comment: @Nick feel free to borrow the idea :)

Comment: Btw, for anyone who wants to be able to easily see the stats of the submitter, and much more, see Scratte's [Review Suggested Edits Rework](https://stackapps.com/q/9106/78873) userscript. An example [user card](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J4Ib6.png) with extra info.

Answer (score -5):

## Blame the system, at least in part

As a high-rep user, I am permitted to edit posts without approval, but I am **not** allowed to approve your edit unilaterally. I have held for years that this is a huge misfeature, and I stand by that assessment today.

Even if I think your edit is perfect, the system incentivizes me to duplicate it rather than approving it. If the changes I want to make are identical to yours, I have two choices: 1) reject your edit and make them myself; 2) approve your edit, *then wait for someone else to do so*. The first way gets the important change registered faster.

For that matter, I probably only *notice* that you had an edit to make because I also wanted to edit the post. The `(1)` next to the `Edit` link only stands out if I am looking at that link, which only happens because I want to click it. Even then, I'm sometimes taken off guard by the popup.

If I think your edit is incomplete, I can replace it (possibly by copying and pasting your version and then continuing work), or I can wait for someone else's approval before adding my bit. The system tells me: plagiarize, else the site temporarily loses functionality.

If I want to make a different change, and I don't want to pass judgment on your change - well, it's in the way. I can reject it to put in my changes, or I can wait. I [cannot](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/397633/is-there-any-way-to-leave-proposed-edits-alone-while-also-editing) preserve your proposal.

In every case, the system incentivizes me to overrule you, regardless of the quality of your contribution. I greatly dislike this.

Comment: I didn't vote, but you're incorrect. You can improve the edit by making further edits to the question, which will preserve the previous editor's edits, and add your own, giving them credit for their edit.

Comment: It hasn't seemed to work like that for me in the past, but I will try to test next chance I get.

Comment: Re *"I am not allowed to approve your edit unilaterally."*: Isn't it approved unilaterally if you choose "Improve Edit"?